# AndEngine beginContact function

Tags: android, andengine

I am designing a simple Android game and I am having problem with collusion.

There is Sprite object and another static sprite object when they collide beginContact(Contact..) function never gets called.

When does this get beginContact function get called? Is there any nice example that u know of?

Thanks for the help.
Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if you can use beginContact on sprites, as far as I know it is tied to the box2D extension. Anyway, I use the following snippet:

```
public boolean setListener(PhysicsWorld mGamePhysicsWorld) {
    mGamePhysicsWorld.setContactListener(new ContactListener() {
        @Override
        public void beginContact(final Contact contact) {
        // do stuff
        }
        public void endContact(Contact contact) {
        // do some other stuff
        });
    return true;
}
```